# Por que no no se asigna el valor en la variable..Trato de asignarlo desde un ciclo for

Tags: python-3.x

```
from time import *



def start():
    
    print("Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos en que lugar de la lista se encuentra el numero que contenga 3 digitos")
    try:
        n1=int(input("Primer Numero "))
        n2=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n3=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n4=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n5=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n6=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n7=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n8=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n9=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n10=int(input("Ultimo Numero "))
        
        list=[n1, n2, n3 ,n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10]
        factorial=1
        resultados={}
        
        

        
#se hace una iteracion y se saca el factorial que se esta iterando, l;uego se reasigna la variable factorial
        for i in list:
              
            while i!=0:
                factorial=i* factorial
                i-=1
                
            resultados[i]=factorial
            factorial=0
        
        if resultados:
            print("Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:\n ")
            for i, e in resultados.items():
                print('El factorial de ', i, ' es: ', e) 
        
            sleep(20)
        
    except:
        print("Debes escribir un valor  entero en cada digito vuelve a intentarlo")
        sleep(3)
        start()
start()
```

Ya he tratado de crear las variables fuera de la funcion y asignarlas global pero nada funciona

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente? Así a primera vista veo una asignación `factorial=0` que debería ser `factorial=1`

Comment: lo que hace el programa es básicamente calcular el factorial de un numero y como debo calcular el fac. de cada uno lo que hago es reasignar factorial a cero, el problema es que en el bucle while cuando intento enviar los datos al diccionario pues no lo hace

Comment: @Ezequiel: si algunas de las respuestas te ha servido de ayuda puedes marcarla como válida. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Varios problemas.

Primero, estas usando un nombre de función como nombre de variable:

```
list=[n1, n2, n3 ,n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10]
```

pero cuando tratas de iterar, Python usa la funciòn list, no tu lista. Eso produce una excepciòn ('type' object is not iterable).

```
for i in list:
```

Este problema se soluciona renombrando la variable como `lista`.

Esto es un error:

```
resultados[i]=factorial
```

debido a que la variable i sale en cero del `while` anterior. O sea, todos los factoriales los guarda bajo la llave 0.

La solución es usar otra variable en el calculo del factorial:

```
    factorial=1            
    valor = i

    while valor != 0:
        factorial = valor * factorial
        valor -= 1

    resultados[i]=factorial
```

También reordene la inicializaciòn de la variable factorial, que siempre debe partir en 1.

Reordene un poco tu programa para poder probarlo màs fácil; no iba a estar ingresando 10 valores cada vez. Aparte de sacar el ingreso de los valores, todo lo demàs està igual

Con todo, queda asi

```
from time import *


def start(lista):
    
    try:
        resultados={}
        
        #   se hace una iteracion y se saca el factorial que se esta iterando, luego se reasigna la variable factorial
        for i in lista:
            factorial=1            
            valor = i

            while valor != 0:
                factorial = valor * factorial
                valor -= 1
            resultados[i]=factorial
        
        if resultados:
            print("Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:\n ")
            for i, e in resultados.items():
                print('El factorial de ', i, ' es: ', e) 
        
            sleep(20)
        
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        sleep(3)

start([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

produce:

```
Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:

El factorial de  1  es:  1
El factorial de  2  es:  2
El factorial de  3  es:  6
El factorial de  4  es:  24
El factorial de  5  es:  120
El factorial de  6  es:  720
El factorial de  7  es:  5040
El factorial de  8  es:  40320
El factorial de  9  es:  362880
El factorial de  10  es:  3628800
```

**Edit: cálculo del factorial**

El cálculo del factorial se puede simplificar usando esta funciòn:

```
def factorial(numero):
    return 1 if numero < 2 else numero * factorial(numero-1)
```

con lo que el còdigo se reduce a:

```
        for i in lista:
            resultados[i]=factorial(i)
```

Màs simple.

Comment: Hey gracias! Soy nuevo en esto y pos no se mucho! Realmente gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Si haces un print de resultados, verás que solamente posee lo siguiente:

```
{0:0}
```

Cuando realmente necesitas algo como esto:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 6, 4: 24, 5: 120, 6: 720, 7: 5040, 8: 40320, 9: 362880, 10: 3628800}
```

Así que cambiaremos el primer for que tienes de esta manera y eliminaremos el while:

```
for i in lista:
            factorial = i*factorial
            resultados[i] = factorial
```

De esta forma simplemente almacenamos los datos, no tienes porque restarle 1 sino la key del diccionario se rodará un elemento y fallará.

De esta forma, el código completo te queda así:

```
from time import *

def start():
    print("Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos en que lugar de la lista se encuentra el numero que contenga 3 digitos")
    try:
        n1=int(input("Primer Numero "))
        n2=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n3=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n4=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n5=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n6=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n7=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n8=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n9=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
        n10=int(input("Ultimo Numero "))

        lista=[n1, n2, n3 ,n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10]
        factorial=1

        resultados={}
        for i in lista:
            factorial = i*factorial
            resultados[i] = factorial

        if resultados:
            print("Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:\n ")
            for i, e in resultados.items():
                print('El factorial de ', i, ' es: ', e)

            sleep(20)
    except:
        print("Debes escribir un valor  entero en cada digito vuelve a intentarlo")
        sleep(3)
        start()
start()
```

El resultado sería:

```
$ -> python3 factorial.py
Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos en que lugar de la lista se encuentra el numero que contenga 3 digitos
Primer Numero 1
Siguiente  Numero 2
Siguiente  Numero 3
Siguiente  Numero 4
Siguiente  Numero 5
Siguiente  Numero 6
Siguiente  Numero 7
Siguiente  Numero 8
Siguiente  Numero 9
Ultimo Numero 10
Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:
 
El factorial de  1  es:  1
El factorial de  2  es:  2
El factorial de  3  es:  6
El factorial de  4  es:  24
El factorial de  5  es:  120
El factorial de  6  es:  720
El factorial de  7  es:  5040
El factorial de  8  es:  40320
El factorial de  9  es:  362880
El factorial de  10  es:  3628800
```

Aunque el código se puede mejorar y optimizar, solamente he cambiado lo necesario para que funcione tal y como lo pides.

Observación:

- No llames a una variable list, esto es una palabra reservada del lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, voy a responder al titulo de tu pregunta.

> Por que no no se asigna el valor en la variable..Trato de asignarlo desde un ciclo for

```
for i in list:
      
    while i!=0:
        factorial=i* factorial
        i-=1
```

Se ejecuta un segundo ciclo (`while`) con una condición que involucra a una variable temporal. `i` toma el valor de cada elemento de list (mal nombrada, ya que `list` ya es otra palabra reservada) y en la linea `i-=1` se está cambiando el valor de `i`.

En vez de no ocurrir la asignación, Lo que ocurre más bien es un a resignación.

Antes de darte una solución, me gustaría hacerte una observación y explicarte por que tu fragmento de código no es lo más apto para conseguir un factorial.

```
for i in list:
      
    while i!=0:
        factorial=i* factorial
        i-=1
        
    resultados[i]=factorial
    factorial=0
```

Este fragmento tiene errores de lógica y emplea técnicas propensas a la falla, pero de momento concentrémonos en lo que es el factorial:

> El factorial de un entero positivo n, el factorial de n o n factorial se define en principio como el producto de todos los números enteros positivos desde 1 hasta n.

Esta operación pone sobre la mesa un concepto llamado recursividad, revisemos la expresión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se puede interpretar como la definición de factorial de forma nativa, una definición que se contiene a sí misma. Básicamente en esto consiste la recursividad.

Dicho esto se puede decir que `3! = 3 * 2!`, que `2! = 2 * 1!`... Se llega a la conslusión que `3! = 6`.

Una función en Python puede cumplir el mismo objetivo:

```
def fac(n):
    factorial = 0
    if n == 0:
        factorial = factorial + 1
    else:
        factorial = n * fac(n - 1)

    return factorial
```

Si se nota, se invoca `fac()` en la propia definición de `fac()`. A esto se le puede llamar una función recursiva. `fac()` cumple su objetivo:

```
print(fac(5))
```

devuelve:

```
120
```

Surge una pregunta muy grande, en cuanto al primer condicional de la función, que evalúa si el parámetro es 0 y devuelve 1. Se puede asumir que `0! = 1`.

**¿Por qué la función evalúa esto, y por qué `0!` = 1?**

Si sigue con la definición de factorial, se podría decir que `0! = 0 * (-1)!`. Por otro lado, la definición dice que el factorial de un número positivo es el producto de 1 hasta ese número.

Si se define como `0!` como 1 se puede decir que `0!` no tiene relevancia en el factorial de un número entero positivo. Esto por que como ya se sabe, `n * 1 = n`.

**Otra manera más divertido de conseguir el factorial de un número entero positivo:**

```
from functools import reduce

def fac(n):
    rango = list(range(1,n + 1,1))
    factorial = reduce(lambda a,b: a * b,rango)
    return factorial
```

Esta función sigue más la definición escrita de *el producto de 1 hasta n*. Explicando un poco el funcionamiento, `rango` es una lista que contiene los números de 1 hasta n y factorial es la multiplicación de todos los elementos de rango.

Por lo tanto, `print(fac(4))` devuelve:

```
24
```

**Solución**

Mi propuesta de solución cambia tu código en muchos aspectos, pero considero que es más óptima

```
from time import *

#Se define la función que va a retornar el factorial del número que se use como argumento
def factorial(numero):
    factorial_ = 0
    if numero == 0:
        factorial_ = factorial_ + 1
    else:
        factorial_ = numero * factorial(numero - 1)

    return factorial_


def start():

    print("Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos en que lugar de la lista se encuentra el numero que contenga 3 digitos")

    lista = []
    #Se automatiza la recolección de datos
    for i in range(10):
        n = int(input("Número "))
        lista.append(n)

    resultados={}
    #Se añade de manera correcta los valores al diccionario
    for i in lista:
        fac = factorial(i)
        resultados.update({i:fac})

    print("Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:\n ")
    for i,j in resultados.items():
        print("El factorial de {} es {}".format(i,j))     
        sleep(20)

start()
```

**Nota:** En los comentarios del código explico por que hago esos cambios.

**¿Qué ha pasado?**

Las principales deficiencias de tu código eran

- La manera en que se intentaba añadir elementos al diccionarios `resultados`
- La falta de automatización

La primera debido a que se usa la expresión `resultados[i]=factorial`, los corchetes en los diccionarios se usan para acceder a una llave en específico. **Los diccionarios no tienen índice**. Estos solo almacenan pares ordenados de llave y valor. Ese tipo de asignación no es soportada, una manera optima es con el método `update()` ([su referencia aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)).

```
resultados.update({i:fac})
```

La segunda ya que bloques de código como este

```
n1=int(input("Primer Numero "))
n2=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n3=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n4=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n5=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n6=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n7=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n8=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n9=int(input("Siguiente  Numero "))
n10=int(input("Ultimo Numero "))
```

No son óptimos, sería más rapido escribir los números en un papel. Cualquier ciclo es bueno para implementar automatización a esto:

```
for i in range(10):
        n = int(input("Número "))
        lista.append(n)
```

**¿Qué resultados da esto?**

Después de quedarme viendo la terminal como tonto por 3 minutos (180 segundos), obtengo resultados correctos. Te dejo el log completo:

```
Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos en que lugar de la lista se encuentra el numero que contenga 3 digitos
Número 1
Número 2
Número 3
Número 4
Número 5
Número 6
Número 7
Número 8
Número 9
Número 10
Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:

El factorial de 1 es 1
El factorial de 2 es 2
El factorial de 3 es 6
El factorial de 4 es 24
El factorial de 5 es 120
El factorial de 6 es 720
El factorial de 7 es 5040
El factorial de 8 es 40320
El factorial de 9 es 362880
El factorial de 10 es 3628800
```

**PD:** Por cierto no sé que se pretende con el `print("Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos en que lugar de la lista se encuentra el numero que contenga 3 digitos")` ya que no viene al caso (en mi opinión), de todos modos lo dejé para que permanezca la integridad de tu código.

**Enlaces que te puede ayudar**

Cosas que usé en los ejemplos y no terminé de explicar:

- [El moódulo `functools` y la función `reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)
- [Expresiones `lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)
- [Respuestas que pierden la integridad del código de la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4752/es-correcto-dar-una-soluci%C3%B3n-que-involucre-cambiar-toda-la-estructura-del-c%C3%B3dig)

Comment: Gracias por los enlaces y por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por la ayuda! Este es mi codigo final...

```
from time import *
resultados={}
lista=[]
contador=1

def factorial(n):
factorial=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    factorial=i * factorial
       
resultados[n]=factorial

def start():
global lista
global contador

print("Escribe 10 numeros y te diremos el factorial de cada uno")
try:
    while contador<11:
        numero=int(input("Introduce el dato: "))
        lista.append(numero)
        contador+=1
    
        #se hace una iteracion y se saca el factorial que se esta iterando, luego se 
        #reasigna la variable factorial
    for i in lista:
        factorial(i)
    
    if resultados:
        print("Aqui presentamos el factorial de los numeros introducidos:\n ")
        for i, e in resultados.items():
            print('El factorial de ', i, ' es: ', e) 
    
        sleep(20)
    
except:
    print("Debes escribir un valor  entero en cada digito vuelve a intentarlo")
    sleep(3)
    start()
start()
```